# Как поменять шрифт пункта меню?

Tags: android, java

Как можно поменять меню на андроид устройстве?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135699/how-to-set-a-font-for-the-options-menu